# Which insect is this? They crawl like caterpillars and get metamorphed into orange moths

Tags: species-identification

[image][image] They are like larvae which gets metamorphed into moth (orange colour with black spots) .They are multiplying rapidly and have spread all over our building.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resembles wooly bear caterpillars while the moth you shown is very identical to black-banded orange moth (Epelis truncataria).